# Dynamic updating price slider

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently comparing our price slider http://www.showstyle.lu/homme/ to that on http://theme-lookz-responsive.webshopapp.com/en/designer/ and as you can see under filters if you drag the filter on our homepage (ShowStyle) the number value of the min & max do not update dynamically i.e. you have to guess where to let go of the slider and hope it lands on a price.

On the example website: if you drag the price filter the min & max values update dynamically making it easier to see what your settings are.

I tried comparing the code of both filter price boxes and saw this additional script they implemented but couldn't figure out if that is what caused it, I think it is but any idea how to re-enact that onto my template? Both are using the same CMS so utilising this code is permitted, it's just a comfort update. I managed to adjust the code but don't understand if I should replace the "ui" syntax with price-filter-range or min/max syntax.

**Original Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#filter_form input, #filter_form select').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });

  $("#collection-filter-price").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    values: [0, 20],
    step: 1,
    slide: function( event, ui){
      $('.sidebar-filter-range .min span').html(ui.values[0]);
      $('.sidebar-filter-range .max span').html(ui.values[1]);

      $('#filter_form_min').val(ui.values[0]);
      $('#filter_form_max').val(ui.values[1]);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
      $('#filter_form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

The 0/20 values are depending on the page you were on so I suppose that also needs to be dynamic based on the highest price item on the current catalog page

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#collection-filter-price").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 750,
  values: [$('#filter_form_min').val(), $('#filter_form_max').val()],
  step: 1,
  slide: function( event, ui){
    $('.price-filter-range .min span').text(ui.values[0]);
    $('.price-filter-range .max span').text(ui.values[1]);
  },
  stop: function(event, ui){
    $('#filter_form_min').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#filter_form_max').val(ui.values[1]);
    $('#filter_form').submit();
  }
});
```

Please note this code (in my answer) been updated from the original due to a misunderstanding. I have also re-edited it to fix functionality that was broken by the inclusion of this code.

Edit: I just noticed that your site already includes the JS code

```
  $(function(){
    $('#filter_form input, #filter_form select').change(function(){
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });

    $("#collection-filter-price").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 750,
      values: [0, 520],
      step: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui){
    $('.sidebar-filter-range .min span').html(ui.values[0]);
    $('.sidebar-filter-range .max span').html(ui.values[1]);

    $('#filter_form_min').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#filter_form_max').val(ui.values[1]);
  },
    stop: function(event, ui){
    $('#filter_form').submit();
  }
    });
  });
```

However this code is being dynamically generated by the server (notice how 520 is embedded into the script)... The only reason it's not working is because it's expecting the class name to be `sidebar-filter-range` instead of `price-filter-range`. If you could just make the correct modification so that it's pointing to the correct elements then it should work.

Comment: Currently don't see any results - since the website is based on the SEOshop CMS, should i implement this on our custom "index" that is present across all pages (like the rest of my general js scripts) or directly on the page where you can find the slider. If the latter, then before or after the price-filter-div (general question) - does it matter?

Comment: @Counterfire This would go directly on the page where you would find the slider. It should go after the elements that it's affecting. To be safe, put it just before the end of your `</body>` tag (inside `<script></script>`). If you want to try it out right now, just take the code, copy it, open up the webpage, then open up the JS console (`CTRL+Shift+J` on most PC browsers) and paste it then press `Enter`. It should run the script and the slider should work. You will need to put the code in again when the page refreshes if you want to do further testing.

Comment: When I test it in the Chrome java console it works but the moment you slide -> the page reloads and the code doesn't function, i'll try placing the code in the core files of the page in the bottom near the footer or on the page of slider and see if it works

Comment: Added it to the page of the slider right at the bottom - it works! Awesome thanks a lot, definitely picked up a new snippet  :)

Comment: @Counterfire Good to know, but please read the edit I just made in my answer :)

Comment: One of the codes directs to the filters and the other to the price slider. There are 2 different portions, but maybe the price slider code is inside the overall filter script, either way i'll have a look to condense it but for now all works perfectly. :)

Comment: Yeah as you assumed the extra script was redundant and just had to rename the first script to pin point to the correct div for the slider

Comment: @Counterfire Yeah I wouldn't have looked further into it but I wanted to go back and take a second look to see where `750` was coming from so it could be dynamically derived the same way I did the `values` array. Then I found the existing code snippet and figured it would be better to mention it to you so that you could avoid any possible glitches in the future if you ever changed it from `750`.